# Tracking my script installation

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am building a CMS/CRM and want to let users install this software on their server using their databases.

I would like to track some of the data from that installation, like version, so I can send updates to that installation if it is out of date. Like when Wordpress tells you a new version is available.

I also want to be able to track the number of users to be able to charge for the installation.

I am using PHP, MySQL(PDO).

Can you let me know what this process is called and any references to this process would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

In your application you may have an array of data you'd like to track; something like this

```
$data = array(
  'domain' => 'http://example.com',
  'version' => '1.4.35',
  'date_added' => '2014-08-20', 
  'last_update' => '2014-08-22'
);
```

Then you could send a request to your server to see if is anything new out there; using cURL or any other method for sending an HTTP request

```
$curl = curl_init("http://your-server.com/your-service/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data)); // convert it to JSON format

$json = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// this is your feedback, in JSON format
$response = json_decode($json, true);
```

It would be good to check the status, like this, but before the `curl_close()` call

```
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($status == 201){
    // ... all fine
}else{
    // otherwise, do something but don't use exit() or die() in this case
}
```

The `$response` value, after decoding, could look something like this

```
array(
  'some_key'     => 'some_value',
  'another_key'  => 'another_value'
  ...
);
```

Now, according to the response, echo a message to the user, like this

```
if(isset($response['some_key']) && $response['some_key'] == 'some_value')){
    echo "An update is out there, <a href=\"http://your-domain.com/update\">Check it out</a>";
}
```

Comment: Great response, thank you. Gonna give it a go. Cheers